# POST request body in Karate throwing error " Arity mismatch: Step Definition 'com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.method(String)

Tags: karate

Hi I have set up Karate and using in my application,I am in initial phase so going through documents and trying to Automate.I am facing this issue and not able to proceed ahead,tried all possibilities.Can any one help me with this why I am seeing this error on my POST "request.cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition 'com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.method(String) in "

Step1)
I am trying to hit POST request[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQYPy.png) on my application .Here is my scenario
Scenario: Verify that JIM IDR request
And header Content-Type = 'Application/json'
And header Accept = 'application/json'
And header Authorization = 'Basic UUEwMl9JbmNlbnRpdmVNYW5hZ2VyXzAwMDJpMTpZWkxaRjlGclR1eWhlcVNJbXlkTlBR'
Given url 'http://{Myurl}/IncentiveManager/0002i1/WCF/V5.svc/InDataRequestCreators'
 When method post

"""

{
     ScenarioId: '9f31c6da-ec56-4360-8589-d21b6320f99b',
     AdapterId: '0fcbd8d2-f5cb-4e2a-bda8-bb37037b022d',
     DataExpiresOnUtc: '2100-01-18T00:00:00',
     CreateScenarioIfMissing: 'false'

}

"""
Then status 201

2)Try
Scenario: Verify that JIM Idr request ofr Post
And header Content-Type = 'Application/json'
And header Accept = 'application/json'
And header Authorization = 'Basic UUEwMl9JbmNlbnRpdmVNYW5hZ2VyXzAwMDJpMTpZWkxaRjlGclR1eWhlcVNJbXlkTlBR'
Given url '{Myurl}/IncentiveManager/0002i1/WCF/V5.svc/InDataRequestCreators'
 When method post

"""
  {
     "ScenarioId": "32lkmsalkclxssss",
     "AdapterId": "0fcbd8d2-f5cb-4e2a-bda8-bb37037b022d",
     "DataExpiresOnUtc": "2100-01-18T00:00:00",
     "CreateScenarioIfMissing": "false"

}
"""
Then status 201

Why I am getting this error everytime

Expected result:-Status 201
Actual result:-It is throwing this following error as mentioned below

cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition 'com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.method(String) in file:/C:/Users/sj13757/.m2/repository/com/intuit/karate/karate-core/0.2.7/karate-core-0.2.7.jar' with pattern [^method (\w+)] is declared with 1 parameters. However, the gherkin step has 2 arguments [post, DocString:
  {
     ScenarioId: '9f31c6da-ec56-4360-8589-d21b6320f99b',
     AdapterId: '0fcbd8d2-f5cb-4e2a-bda8-bb37037b022d',
     DataExpiresOnUtc: '2100-01-18T00:00:00',
     CreateScenarioIfMissing: 'false'

}

]. 
Step: When method post
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.arityMismatch(StepDefinitionMatch.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.transformedArgs(StepDefinitionMatch.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)

Comment: sorry you need to format this better for anyone to make sense of what's going on.

Comment: @Peter :-I have edited the above request,Can u help me with that? i am stuck in between.I have attached image too,Line number 19.

Comment: I looked at the screenshot. you are using such an old version of karate (0.2.7) that there is no point in trying to analyze this. and the error is clear, line 21 onwards is wrong. you should have `when request` with that triple-quote section before the line 19. read the doc carefully. go through the demos carefully please. jeez.